# gradle build warning when running app, cant run app

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, apache-httpclient-4.x, build.gradle

I am quite new to android and cant understand this error.When sync the gradle file, android studio is exiting without any error but when I am trying to build the app and run it it gives 2 warnings as:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages

warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages......
```

.......

my gradle file is this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo'
    }
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()

}

 android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.cornerstores.cornerfresh"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile([group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-android', version: '1.20.0'])
    compile([group: 'com.appspot.corner_fresh', name: 'fresh_api', version: 'v1-1.20.0-SNAPSHOT'])
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.18.0-rc') {
        // Exclude artifacts that the Android SDK/Runtime provides.
        exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'shared'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
        exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
    }

    // Add the Android extensions for the Google API client library.
    // This will automatically include play services as long as you have download that library
    // from the Android SDK manager.
    // Add the Android extensions for the Google API client library.
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.18.0-rc') {
        // Exclude play services, since we're not using this yet.
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services', module: 'google-play-services')
    }
    // END Google APIs
    // The following client libraries make HTTP/JSON on Android easier.
    // Android extensions for Google HTTP Client.
    compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.18.0-rc') {
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
    }
    // This is used by the Google HTTP client library.
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile files('libs/fresh_api-v1-1.20.0-SNAPSHOT.jar')

}
```

I tried everything I can find on stackoverflow but still it is showing the error. Couldn't find any proper answer to this. Kindly suggest the solution. I am stuck in my project due to this. Thanks

Comment: Those are warnings, not errors.

Comment: @JaredBurrows but its not compiling due to it and I cant find any solution too.

Comment: What was the last dependency you added that caused it to stop working?

Comment: @JaredBurrows `compile files('libs/fresh_api-v1-1.20.0-SNAPSHOT.jar')` ?? thats the cloud endpoint api that i am importing. any suggestion??

Comment: I am not even sure what the library is. You should try to only use Gradle dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Even if this question is quite old, it is unresolved and I struggled myself for some time to find the reason in a similar configuration.

You excluded the duplicated imports in the libraries, but you imported Google-Apis twice.

The exclude-part needs to be in

```
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.18.0-rc') {
    // Exclude artifacts that the Android SDK/Runtime provides.
    exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'shared'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
}
```

and in your example you again included the apis by:

```
compile([group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-android', version: '1.20.0'])
```

without the exclude-part which caused the duplicate import.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try of deleting the line: 
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to exlude it twice like so .. I don't think it's too complicated but it can be be confusing. I think it's better to solve those warning beacause they may come back in weird forms afterwards.

```
compile ('com.google.apis:google-api-services-urlshortener:v1-rev47-1.22.0'){
    exclude module: 'httpclient' //by artifact name
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' //by group
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient' //by both name and group
}

compile ('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.21.0') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient' //by artifact name
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' //by group
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient' //by both name and group
}
```